# How to make a mysql statement for sent log

Tags: mysql, update, insert

I have a table called "make_sent_log"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `make_sent_log` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `transaction_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `total_base` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `delivered` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `pending` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `transaction_id` (`transaction_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

My goal is store delivery status of mobile numbers

**For ex: sent bulk sms to 5 mobile Numbers**

one unique transaction id will generated then I store it to the `transaction_id` column ex:- `transaction_id` = `trans_1`

I sent sms to 5 Mobile Numbers so I store it to the `total_base` column
ex:- `total_base` = `5`

If sms sent successfully to the only 3 Mobiles, `delivered` = `3`

So other numbers in pending stage so `pending` = `2`

So My table looks like

```
INSERT INTO `make_sent_log` (`id`, `transaction_id`, `total_base`, `delivered`, `pending`) VALUES
(1, 'trans_1', 5, 3, 2);
```

[image]

My doubt is after some 1 or 2 Minutes, 2 pending numbers can be delivered so How to set

```
delivered = 5
```

And `pending = 0`

See below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In next iteration, you may need to check if there are pending numbers to send sms. If pending count is greater than zero then need to send sms to those pending numbers.

track success_count after resending sms to pending numbers.

Then, need to increment delivered count and decrement pending count with this success_count.

So,

```
delivered  = delivered + success_count
pending = pending - success_count
```

then you may need to execute update on make_sent_log table with this updated delivered and pending counts.

```
update `make_sent_log` set delivered = delivered, pending = pending where transaction_id = 'trans_1';
```

Continue this iteration cycle until pending count = zero.